# Have to ctrl+C twice after :w

Tags: vim

I'm running vim 7.4 on latest OSX and all of the sudden have to ctrl+c twice after write mode. If I do not ctrl+c twice, here's what happens:

- Send :w command

Bottom line looks like: "test.scala 27L, 915C"

- Press a key (let's say j)

Bottom line looks like: "test.scala 27L, 915Cj"

.. and my input keeps getting appended to the bottom until I ctrl+c twice. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar experience. I guess you have plugin syntastic installed. When you save your file, the plugin will check the syntax errors in your file. If your file is big or has many referenced stuff, it could be slow. In my case, I open one java file, and save, it took quite long time.

First locate the problem:  deactivate your syntastic plugin, open the same file and save again, see if the lag's gone. If yes, you can config the plugin, either map the command of toggle or create some rule so that in certain case disable the plugin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. I disabled syntastic for now and will reconfigure it later.